# What is the quickest way to animate lights flashing on and off in a pattern?

Tags: animation

I have a wall of cubes which i want to light up so they look like an equalizer. So each cubes switches between a diffuse and emission shader in a pattern. Is there an easier way to do this than manually going through and keyframing it all?

Comment: Have a look at this guy's blend file: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/86929/38953  He is using an amplitude curve from a digital recording to make icospheres dance.  You may be able to make a script (or drivers) to use the amplitude values to "light up" certain cubes.

Comment: Possibly related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47375/how-to-control-many-tiny-lights/47385#47385

Comment: You can bake sound to an F curve and use that to drive any property (like brightness) there are plenty of [videos online](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+bake+sound+to+f+curve)

Comment: You could also have a look at [animation nodes](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+animation+nodes+sound).