# How many frames are there in one minute Animation?

Tags: animation

I want to know how many frames I need for a one minute Animation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What settings do I change to render an animation of 60 fps instead of 24 fps for video editing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180419/what-settings-do-i-change-to-render-an-animation-of-60-fps-instead-of-24-fps-for)

Comment: @Gorgious not sure that ones relates to this one., I am  sure there are dupes tho...  finding them gets more and more difficult..  Have added an answer till one is found.

Comment: @susu is that really what the user was asking? Sorry, I interpreted it more as in "*What FPS value should I use in my animation?*", not so much as math problem of calculating "*How many frames do I need for one minute?*", hence closing as opinion.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos It is indeed hard to guess what the OP "wanted", but what is written can be answered... All good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on your frame rate.

One minute = $60$ seconds.

To know the frames needed for a minute at a given frame rate (FPS) is a simple multiplication:

*Frames Per Second* X $60$ = *number of frames in a minute*

To View the Frame Rate, go to the "Output Properties" on the right side menu below the render settings. there is an option of Frame Rate.

[image]

The default FPS is usually 24 or 25.

You can change this according to your desired Frames Per Seconds(FPS )

Answer (score 5):

**There are utility python methods for this**

How many frames will depend on the frame rate of your current scene.

The frame rate is determined by the frames per second integer `fps` and the frames per seconds base `fps_base`

so actual frame rate is `fps / fps_base`

Fortunately the devs have given us a convenience method to work out how many frames or how much time. In this case

```
>>> bpy.utils.time_to_frame(
time_to_frame(time, fps=None, fps_base=None)
Returns a float frame number from a time given in seconds or
as a datetime.timedelta object.
If *fps* and *fps_base* are not given the current scene is used.
:arg time: time in seconds.
:type time: number or a ``datetime.timedelta`` object
:return: the frame.
:rtype: float
```

Hence for a scene render fps selected as value 24 (default)

```
>>> C.scene.render.fps
24

>>> C.scene.render.fps_base
1.0

>>> bpy.utils.time_to_frame(60)
1440.0
```

requires 10 gross or 1440 frames to render out a minute.

If the rate is set to the dropdown option "29.97 fps"

```
>>> C.scene.render.fps
30

>>> C.scene.render.fps_base
1.0010000467300415

>>> bpy.utils.time_to_frame(60)
1798.2017142557036
```

Hence at this rate would require 1799 frames to clock up a minute.  The partner in crime method will confirm

```
>>> bpy.utils.time_from_frame(
time_from_frame(frame, fps=None, fps_base=None)
Returns the time from a frame number .
If *fps* and *fps_base* are not given the current scene is used.
:arg frame: number.
:type frame: int or float.
:return: the time in seconds.
:rtype: datetime.timedelta

>>> bpy.utils.time_from_frame(1799)
datetime.timedelta(seconds=60, microseconds=26636)
```

Note the above  `>>>` is typed into the python console area.

Answer (score 1):

You can do math inside of any entry box.  So you can select your *End* frame and enter the *Frame Rate* * 60 to calculate the frames for one minute.

[image]